# Concurrent operations on a Vector (or Vector of Vectors)

Tags: multithreading, vector, rust, concurrency

I'm about to write a Rust program where I would like to implement concurrency. My data will be stored in a Vector, or Vector of Vectors, whichever I can make work the easiest. Here is some pseudocode to show how the struct and vectors will be set up. Obviously syntax is not correct.

```
struct Artifact
    identifier = "abc123";
    vector_containing_Line_structs = [struct Line, struct Line, struct Line, ..., etc];
    // ^ this vector will contain thousands of line structs

struct Line
    line_type = 1
    speed = 5
    array_length = 4;
    array = {10, 20, 30, 40}
```

Essentially, this is how I am currently thinking about storing my data (open to ideas). Later in the program, I would like to use multi-threading to concurrently perform calculations on subsets of the `vector_containing_Line_structs` vector. Thread1 operates on indices 0-10000, thread2 operates on indices 10001-20000, etc. Threads are read-only, they will not be writing anything back to the Line structs, just accessing the array and struct 'variables' within each one.

Will the rust compiler let different threads operate on items within the same vector concurrently? Alternatively, is there a way I can split up this data so that it is organized in a fashion that preserves order/indexing and allows concurrent calculations in a similar fashion?

-- My only other idea was a vector of vectors. `vector some_vector = [ [10k Line structs], [10k Line Structs], ... ]`. I would hope Rust would let me dole out each sub-vector to different threads.

Comment: *Will the rust compiler let different threads operate on items within the same vector concurrently* - yes - if your threads don't write to the array, they can access it concurrently as much as they like.

Comment: You may be interested in the [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/) crate, such as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fa836efc345e0a22bd31b618262869df).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is not specific to the members of the structures, but about the ability to read data from a shared vector across multiple threads,
here is a trivial example working on a simple vector of integers.

References or slices cannot directly be passed to a thread because the compiler cannot prove that referenced data will live longer than the thread.
Then we use an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) that will keep these data alive as long as the threads exist.

Obtaining some partial results from the threads is usually done with a [`mpsc` channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html).

See the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-01-threads.html).

```rust
fn main() {
    // prepare vector to be shared
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10_000 {
        data.push(i);
    }
    // make it accessible to multiple threads
    let data = std::sync::Arc::new(data);
    // prepare communication channel
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    // launch the desired number of threads
    let thread_count = 8;
    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for idx in 0..thread_count {
        // clone shared ressources in order to move them into the thread
        let tx = tx.clone();
        let data = data.clone();
        threads.push(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // determine the part of shared data to be accessed by this thread
            let begin = data.len() * idx / thread_count;
            let end = data.len() * (idx + 1) / thread_count;
            let slc = &data[begin..end];
            // work on this slice
            let mut sum = 0;
            for v in slc {
                sum += v;
            }
            println!("thread {} --> {}", idx, sum);
            // send a result to main thread
            tx.send(sum).unwrap();
        }));
    }
    // wait for threads and collect results
    let mut result = 0;
    for th in threads {
        result += rx.recv().unwrap();
        th.join().unwrap();
    }
    println!("done: {}", result);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this without having to clone() the shared resources? I have a lot of data, and my gut says clone might be expensive just to set up multi-threading. 

Also, how expensive is this line: let data = std::sync::Arc::new(data); ?

I'm relatively new to this, apologies if these are basic questions. I've only done multi-threading in C in a school setting.

Comment: @scotty-nukem The `clone()` calls here are lightweight and were designed with this usage in mind. Cloning an `Arc` is just a bit more than cloning the pointer, but the actual data is not duplicated, it is shared. The same goes for the `tx` end of the channel. All of this if well explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-00-concurrency.html).

Comment: @scotty-nukem And about `let data = std::sync::Arc::new(data);` the original data is moved (not cloned) into a kind of heap-allocated box dedicated to shared references across threads. This move operation only duplicates the few bytes (pointer+capacity+size) the vector is made of but not its whole content (still known through the pointer). [This page](https://hashrust.com/blog/moves-copies-and-clones-in-rust/) illustrates this.

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah. New to StackOverflow as well. Answer accepted.